# Cannot call 'strategy.close' with argument 'when'='long'

Tags: pine-script

Let me start off by saying I'm very new to `Pine Script` and i think my problem is trivial but i didn't find much on it.

Let's say for example I want the make a strategy that would buy when `EMA25` crosses over `EMA200` and sell when it goes under without the need for `limit` `stop` or `loss`

```
//@version=5
strategy("Pine Script EMA Strategy", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100, default_qty_value = 100, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)

EMA25 = ta.ema(close, 25)
EMA200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

plot(EMA25, color=color.red, title="EMA25")
plot(EMA200, color=color.yellow, title="EMA200")

bool longPositionCondition = ta.crossover(EMA25, EMA200)
bool exitLong = ta.crossover(EMA200, EMA25)

if (exitLong)
    bool exitWorkAround = true
else
    bool exitWorkAround = false

if (longPositionCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("exit", "long", when = exitLong)
```

Whenever I try to execute this code I get this error:
`Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 20: Cannot call 'strategy.close' with argument 'when'='long'. An argument of 'literal string' type was used but a 'series bool' is expected`

I've been looking into this problem for a while but I still don't know what exactly what I'm doing wrong,
it seems to ask for a `boolean` variable in `when =` but says it's `'when'='long'` which as far as I understood is the id for `strategy.entry` so it doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the signature of the `strategy.close()` function by Ctrl+clicking on it. Here's the signature:

```
strategy.close(id, when, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message) → void
```

The first argument is `id`, i.e. the id of the order that you want to exit from (so it has to be the same that you specified in `strategy.entry()`, where the order was created). The second argument is `when`, i.e. when the exit should happen. You first pass `"long"` to it implicitly, by putting the `"long"` string in the second position, which is why the script doesn't compile.

This will compile:

```
if (longPositionCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.close("long", when = exitLong)
```

Comment: ah, I see where I went wrong, I changed `strategy.exit` to `strategy.close` without changing what's inside the parentheses. but I still get no data when i add it to the chart, what can i do to make it buy&exit with only `when`?